# Highcharts - title per column

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

I am currently using Highcharts in a React app to display 2 columns of data.

I have a request to append a title to each column, ideally I need to do something like this -

[image]

I was thinking about trying to use annotations and styling them to look like titles, however couldn't get this to work. Is this effect posisble?

Comment: For a regular column you could use `dataLabels`, for stacked, look at `stackLabels`: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.stackLabels. Or, just use `labels`: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/labels

Comment: This is possible by using [`stackLabels.formatter`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.stackLabels.formatter) as jlbriggs says, example: http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/me9pyzqv/2/